# When does LinkedBlockingQueue outperform ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Tags: java, performance, locking, lock-free

I need to simulate a scenario where blocking algorithms are faster than their non-blocking counterparts, mainly due to the overhead that the latter incur. I'm thinking about using Java's `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for this scenario.

Can anyone suggest a scenario where `LinkedBlockingQueue` is faster than `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`?

Comment: Too low rep to comment, but maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843012/why-use-concurrentlinkedqueue-when-we-have-linkedblockingqueue

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680869/do-lock-free-algorithms-really-perform-better-than-their-lock-full-counterparts

Comment: It depends a bit what you define as "outperform" - e.g. lock-free algorithms may produce higher CPU load, while still increasing throughput. You could try the single-threaded edge-case as a scenario where the added cost of the lock-free implementation yields no benefit.

Comment: Perhaps really high contention, especially from more threads than you have cores if the backoff mechanism are different for locks vs. whatever `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` does.  Lock-free algorithms are often good when contention is low-ish so it's rare to actually have to retry.  (The opposite of what happens when people microbenchmark with n threads hammering on something without doing any other real work in between).